# How to check the size of values in a particular column by reading csv in python

Tags: python

[image]

When I call a csv file, I want to compare whether the values in a particular column are greater than a particular value. Then, I'd like to put on a pop-up window.

```
import ctypes
import csv

        reader = csv.reader(csv_file_name)

        for row in reader:
            if(row[3]>=5):
                mymessage = 'A message'
                title = 'Popup window'
                ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxA(0, mymessage, title, 0)
            else:
                continue
```

To solve this problem, I wrote the code above and there was no response. Here, I want to check if the values in the column are each greater than "5" and show a pop-up window. What part of the code is wrong?

Comment: try `int(row[3]) >= 5` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a csv with following data:

[image]

**code worked:** on adding `int(row[3])>=5`

```
import ctypes
import csv

with open('data.csv') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    for row in reader:
        if(int(row[3])>=5):
            mymessage = 'A message'
            title = 'Popup window'
            ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxA(0, mymessage, title, 0)
        else:
            continue
```

**result:**
[image]

Comment: In my case, the first line consisted of strings such as A, B, C, and D. Thus, an error of `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10` occurred when `int(row[3])` was given. To prevent this, the `next(reader)` code should be added so that it can be read from the second line.

Comment: one suggestion, when I have to work with csv data and perform multiple operations I generally use [pandas data frame](https://pandas.pydata.org/). It is easy to learn and work with.

Answer (score 0):

```
import ctypes
import csv

reader = csv.reader(csv_file_name)

for index, row in enumerate(reader):
    if row == 3:
        for cell in row: 
            if cell >= 5: 
                mymessage = 'A message'
                title = 'Popup window'
                ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxA(0, mymessage, title, 0)
            else:
                continue
```

Try using this code. You don't need to compare the entire column, but only the cells inside this column